# Role of derived keys in EAP-PSK in WPA-2

Tags: wifi, wpa2, wpa2-psk

I'm currently trying to understand WPA-2 and I've discovered that it's built on the EAP-PSK protocol which sets up some keys derived from the SSID name and a password.

I assume that the keys derived from EAP-PSK, namely AK and TEK, are used in the 4-way handshake to verify that the 2 parties have generated on each derivative level the correct keys (KDK vs MSK and EMSK). (see the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4764#page-12))

What I don't understand is which type of key is used for message encryption in WPA2-PSK after the 4-way handshake is successful. Is it through extended authentication with TEK key?

Edit: I am aware of [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/four-way-handshake-in-wpa-personal-wpa-psk) and the book presented in the voted answer. Unfortunately, the book has different notations compared to the RFC and I'm looking for a more precise answer that tells me exactly which is the key used in the encryption after the handshake is successful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Four-way Handshake in WPA-Personal (WPA-PSK)](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/four-way-handshake-in-wpa-personal-wpa-psk)

Comment: I've searched through the [libtins library](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins) and found that there isn't any AK, TEK or EMSK keys derived in the WPA2 protocol. The 4 way handshake happens differently in WPA2 than presented in the RFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to understand is that EAP is less of a protocol, and more of a framework.  The terminology from [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/four-way-handshake-in-wpa-personal-wpa-psk) is valid because of the following quote from the [IEEE 802.11i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004) wiki page:

> To derive the PMK from the PSK, the PSK is put through PBKDF2-SHA1 as
> the cryptographic hash function. If an 802.1X EAP exchange was carried
> out, the PMK is derived from the EAP parameters provided by the
> authentication server.

So when EAP-PSK is configured a four-way handshake occurs with a client to essentially establish authentication to the AP.  The result of that authentication is essentially the PMK.  [This link](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/100611/80211-sniffer-capture-analysis-wpawpa2-psk-or-eap) explains the difference between using WPA2-PSK and WPA2-PEAP.  I know it's not exactly the same, but you can see that a separate exchange occurs before the WPA2 four-way handshake.

The entire EAP-PSK process outlined in [RFC4764](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4764#page-12) is only used to establish authentication and secure channels to relay the PMK to the client. Which I believe is the MSK/EMSK since they're not mentioned at all in the RFC after derivation.  Then that's used as the basis for the rest of WPA2 setup.

I agree this is confusing, and wireless technology is really just black magic with dragons taking your packets to places.

---

Now the `libtins` library uses the PMK and PTK terminology.  Their WPA2 session keys are derived in [src/crypto.cpp](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/blob/cab0ba8b9a152f291210f0101bef246a3974f67b/src/crypto.cpp).

Comment: Indeed, the fact that WPA2-PSK is called this way is because of the 4-way handshake and the RFC4764 should be consider a framework (WPA2 uses with slightly different parameters).