# Create Evil Twin with encryption and intercept input

Tags: wpa2, evil-twin

I know how to create an Evil Twin of a WiFi network using Hostapd. However, I can only create an unencrypted network  with eventually a fake login page.

While this can be work with some kind of people, many others can easily understand something it's wrong with their connection.

So I was thinking: it's possible to create an Evil Twin with any type of encryption (standard UIs in OS doesn't show it at the moment of connection) with no /random password (and maybe username) being asked at the moment of connection and sniffed?

So the Evil Twin seems the "good" Twin even in authentication and it can sniff username/ password without login pages that doesn't appear in standard WEP/WPA/WPA2 networks.

Comment: In windows you can use your virtual ap to create a wpa2 network and use the same passphrase (If you know it) as the target, so he can connect automatically to your network with the credentials he have on his device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. On WEP/WPA/WPA2 the key exchange is done in a "secure" way and the password is not transmitted in clear text on a client connection. You can find more information about the key exchange on this another security stack exchange question: [Four-way Handshake in WPA-Personal (WPA-PSK)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/four-way-handshake-in-wpa-personal-wpa-psk)

It has interesting links and documentation about how 4-way-handshake works (applicable to WPA and WPA2). WEP has also handshakes but they work in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that was impossible for a reason like this. I'll read the documentation!

Comment: If you know the passphrase you can merge your AP with target's network, like a Rogue AP instead of an Evil Twin

Comment: The question is not "can the password be sniffed", but "can the evil twin make clients connect to it and send IP packets". I googled this question for an hour and did not find any answer. This one is the closest. So please clarify.